# How To replace text in footer/header in batch of folder of word files using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a question about replacing footer and header using VBA
I have a code, the code can replace all text in one folder of a word file
I get this code script from
https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/find-replace-contents-multiple-word-documents/
Here the Code

```
  Sub FindAndReplaceInFolder()
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim strFindText As String
  Dim strReplaceText As String
 
  '  Pop up input boxes for user to enter folder path, the finding and replacing texts.
  strFolder = InputBox("Enter folder path here:")
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\" & "*.docx", vbNormal)
  strFindText = InputBox("Enter finding text here:")
  strReplaceText = InputBox("Enter replacing text here:")
 
  '  Open each file in the folder to search and replace texts. Save and close the file after the action.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
    With objDoc
      With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
          .text = strFindText
          .Replacement.text = strReplaceText
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Format = False
          .MatchCase = False
          .MatchWholeWord = False
          .MatchWildcards = False
          .MatchSoundsLike = False
          .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      objDoc.Save
      objDoc.Close
      strFile = Dir()
    End With
  Wend
End Sub
```

My question is how to replace specifically just for footer/header?
Because this code only can replace a text on a body of word files

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You need to be trying yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask See also: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/BatchFR.htm Headers and footers are in a different story from the main text. https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/process_batch_folder_addin.html http://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm

Comment: Okee thank you for your advice sir

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/19388-find-replace-header-footer-1000-files.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modified the code and it works well for me to answer my case question

Here is my code

```
Sub FindAndReplaceInFolder()
 Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim strFindText As String
  Dim strReplaceText As String
  Dim xSelection As Selection
  Dim xSec As Section
  Dim xHeader As HeaderFooter
  Dim xFooter As HeaderFooter
 
  '  Pop up input boxes for user to enter folder path, the finding and replacing texts.
  strFolder = InputBox("Enter folder path here:")
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\" & "*.docx", vbNormal)
  strFindText = InputBox("Enter finding text here:")
  strReplaceText = InputBox("Enter replacing text here:")
 
  '  Open each file in the folder to search and replace texts. Save and close the file after the action.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
    With objDoc
    For Each xSec In objDoc.Sections
        For Each xHeader In xSec.Headers
            xHeader.Range.Select
            Set xSelection = objDoc.Application.Selection
            With xSelection
                .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
                With xSelection.Find
                .Text = strFindText
                .Replacement.Text = strReplaceText
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                End With
                xSelection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next xHeader
        For Each xFooter In xSec.Footers
            xFooter.Range.Select
            Set xSelection = objDoc.Application.Selection
            With xSelection
                .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
                With xSelection.Find
                .Text = strFindText
                .Replacement.Text = strReplaceText
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                End With
                xSelection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next xFooter
    Next xSec
    objDoc.Save
    objDoc.Close
    strFile = Dir()
    End With
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no need to select the header or footer. The `Find` method is also available from the `Range` object. When writing VBA code you should avoid using `Selection`.